# The usage of the word 'consequent'

Tags: word-usage

My question is how to use the word 'consequent' ? what is the preposition that follows the word 'consequent' ?

Comment: *Consequent* is normally an adjective. As such, I can't think of an example of a preposition ever following it. (It can also be a noun, but the same applies to that.)

Comment: Consequent is a noun in Logic. Not to be confused with consequence.

Comment: There was a fall in price consequent **to** a rise in production. ('stolen' from here: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/consequent )

Answer (score 1):

As Jason says, it's usually an adjective. For example:

> "Because of his diet and consequent loss of weight his clothes no longer fitted."

It means his loss of weight was a consequence, or a result, of his diet. In other words, his diet *led to* or *caused* his loss of weight.

I don't remember seeing it followed by a preposition. It doesn't need one.

However, the two online dictionaries I've looked at say that "consequent on" and "consequent upon" are allowed in the US. None of the 22 examples of 'consequent' at [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/consequent) use 'upon'. Only two use 'on'. This is the shortest and simplest:

> "You've got a university place consequent on your exam results."

In the UK we would say 'because of your exam results, or 'following...' or 'due to...' or 'owing to...'.

We might possibly say 'as a consequence of your exam results,' but Lexico defines 'consequence' as '*A result or effect, **typically one that is unwelcome or unpleasant**'.* 'Her consequent poverty' seems to me a more apt use of the word than 'Her consequent wealth'.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/consequent-on) defines 'consequent on' as '*following as a result of*', which is poor English. They must mean 'following' **or** 'as a result of.'

Until a better answer comes along I would suggest that you try **not** to follow 'consequent' with a preposition. There are plenty of examples of its correct usage at the two dictionaries mentioned.

Comment: *Consequent on* doesn't sound normal to me. The use of *consequent on* in your example sentence looks like a misuse of the word—and I would rephrase it as *You had good exam results and a consequent university placement.* I suppose I wouldn't say that *consequent on* is actually wrong, if it's used that way by some, but, to me, it sounds like a confused mix between *pending* and *because of*. However, somebody arguing in favour of it might equate it with its synonymous *resulting from*, which does sound okay to me. So, I suppose it's somewhat subjective.

Comment: @ Jason Bassford  Yes - I agree with all that. It's hard to believe that example sentence came from Lexico. I'm really losing confidence in online dictionaries! [Where did the 'for' come from in the verb 'advocate for'?]